# Adding Greater than or equal to constraint

Tags: swift, view, autolayout

Can anyone suggest me how to add greater than or equal to constraint for view designed in storyboard using swift.

Answer (score -1):

Add your view... add constraints... select the constraint you want to be Greater Than or Equal to... change its **Relation** property.

Here I've added a view and given it Width, Height and Center X/Y constraints:

[image]

With the Width constraint selected, I can change it from **Equal** to **Greater Than or Equal** (or **Less Than or Equal**):

[image]